# How does partitioning is generated on oracle Exadata?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, exadata

I want to know how oracle created it because i want to be able to have all month partition in single TBS for back-up purposes ,example of partition name oracle automatically generated is '***SYS_P321847***'

Comment: How does the table DDL define the partitions? I'm pretty sure you'd have to create the partitions manually. [This may be related](http://oracletoday.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/tablespace-selection-in-interval.html). And is this really related to Exadata?

Comment: actually , i am using Interval Partitioning in which is in my understanding i only generate the 1st partition then oracle automatically generate the new partition as data comes , my real concern is how oracle generate the partition name , how can i tell by looking at the partition name which data it conatin.

Comment: From the `high_value` in `user_tab_columns`, as that article shows. It's a LONG column which makes it a bit awkward to work with. Your question seems to be about which tablespace each partition goes into, and whether/how you can control that, though?

Comment: Yaa thanks for the help , this didn't exactly fix my problem but i am now on the right track,i guess in the end i cant tell from the name which data it contain so that i could created some automatic rules for moving partition.many thanks..

Comment: It may also help to know that you can reference partitions by value with the `PARTITION FOR (key)` syntax shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51143).